# Inserting a javascript file into an existing html file using a script

Tags: vi, ex

After an certain html page is generated by a publishing program I want to include some javascript in the  element. I am in the middle of a script setting up some parameters that are needed to run the website and wanted to include the insertion of the javascript in the script. I thought I could use vi but after searching for ways to use vi in a script, stackoverflow convinced me that ex should be used not vi.
My problem is I can't get ex to :r .
I wanted to:

```
    ex html.file <<EOF
    /head
    n (ending </head tag)
    O open line above
    -----can't code an ESC
    r javascriot file
    wq
    EOF
```

Any help of other suggestions would be appreciated.